# Make Windows search treat hyphen as a word separator

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-search

I have a bunch of images whose filenames contain "y-tho":
[image]

But when I search for "y-tho" I get nothing:
[image]

File Explorer already treats the hyphen as a word separator, because pressing `Ctrl`+`Left-/Right-arrow` during a rename makes the cursor jump to hyphens, but I guess Windows Search doesn't?
Is there any way to alleviate this?

TBH being unable to search is not worth the possible portability loss caused by using the whitespace character.

Comment: Is the location you'e searching indexed? When I createed sample files, they were found. But, I would suggest trying the following (one at a time): `name:~"*y-tho*"` , `name:~"*y?tho*"` (check for non-standard hyphen)...

Comment: It's not indexed! Does that affect how one needs to search? Also, both your suggestions worked! Actually even just `*y-tho*` worked, with the only difference being the filenames weren't all yellow this time.